# DatePicker using html , css , java script with out using HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am looking for a good and simple datepicker to my java web application. I am using struts2 , HTML , jsp, Hibernate. I have little knowledge on CSS, java script but it is out of my range to create a datepicker for my application. Can some one help me with any api's that supports the technologies which I am using or any link where I can pick a reusable datapicker code snippet.

I have no knowledge in JQuery but would like to use it for this datepicker if it's not taking much of my time to implement as I am not in a position to spend much time for just one datepicker implementaion.

Comment: A simple Google Search yields tons of great HTML+JS+CSS datepickers.

Comment: @ItsGreg: trust me. I have gone through so many links and examples and non of them helped me. came here after spending 2 days completely on searching on many blogs and examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use native jquery ui [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Follow this steps:

1. First include jquery ui library in your project:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`
2. Define you input with a custom class:

   `<input type="text" class="datepicker">`
3. To finish, just call jquery datepicker on page load:

   `<script>
     $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
    </script>`

It`s pretty simple, follow this steps and it will work. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks you so much @Tulio Castro. It's working perfectly fine. I have followed your instructions. It was very helpful.

Comment: Castro: I am facing small issue. the CSS font used in the example page of JQuery UI lib gives me the correct look and feel of the datepicker in my jsp page, since the font declarations are given in the body tag level as below it is effecting the other elements look and feel. below is the code in my jsp page


    <style>
 body{
  font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
 }
 
 </style>

I have changed the above code to some thing like 
#myDatepicker
{
 font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
}
and using it in the datepicker form element but no use

Comment: also you have edited your answer from $("#datepicker") to $(".datepicker"). It was working only with #datepicker and not working if i use $(".datepicker")... Please have a check and comment on this change?

Comment: Yes i've made this edit. To use $('#datepicker') your input needs id="datepicker". In the other hand, if you use $('.datepicker') your input needs class="datepicker". It is better to use class, that way you can have many inputs as you wish. If you use ID, only one datepicker can be used. It is clear enough ?

Comment: Castro: I am facing issues in adding multiple datepicker's. It is only working if I use the HTML Input tag for text filed and If I am using the struts tag for the text field then the calender is not getting popped up. I have tried to use only HTML input tag but if I use it then the textfiled is getting aligned on top of all the other form elements and what ever the calender that is getting popping is over lapping with other form element which is very annoying. Please help me.